easepick: RangePlugin not found
I'm trying to add a calendar with the option to enable range selection. I've used the following line to install it:
npm install @easepick/bundle

Then, I used the following to import it:
import { easepick, RangePlugin }  from '@easepick/bundle';

After this, I try to create a field with the following code:
const picker = new easepick.create({
    element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    css: [
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/core@1.2.1/dist/index.css',
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/range-plugin@1.2.1/dist/index.css',
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/preset-plugin@1.2.1/dist/index.css',
    ],
    plugins: ['RangePlugin'],
});

After this, when I click on the field, calendar does popup however, I'm able to select only one date. In the console logs, I get

easepick: RangePlugin not found.

I tried to import everything individually and to install just the core and the related package, but the same message is showing in the console (and I'm unable to select the range).

Just had to do the same, the issue is the referencing of the plugins. The plugins option should have the plugin classes themselves, not as strings.
Here's what worked for me:
import { easepick } from '@easepick/core';
import { RangePlugin } from '@easepick/range-plugin';
import { PresetPlugin } from '@easepick/preset-plugin';

const picker = new easepick.create({
    element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    css: [
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/core@1.2.1/dist/index.css',
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/range-plugin@1.2.1/dist/index.css',
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/preset-plugin@1.2.1/dist/index.css',
    ],
    plugins: [RangePlugin, PresetPlugin],
});

